# How can I get started building a Facebook application with a Java server backend?

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, rest

I want to utilise the Facebook JavaScript API in the client, but manage app logic and configuration on the server through REST web services. I've tried a lot of tutorials out there, but so far I haven't seen one that actually works.

- What do you recommend as a server / web framework?
- What technology should I use for my REST endpoints?
- How can I host this application in a place where facebook will "see" it as a valid app?

I'm looking for a comprehensive tutorial or set of recommended practices to get started.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just so happened to create a blog series that takes you through EVERYTHING you will need.  The articles:

- Setup Eclipse (IDE) and JBoss AS7 (server)
- Setup other JBoss Tools including Forge
- Setup JAX-RS Web Service in Java using Forge (very easy!)
- Setup account to Host the site for FREE with OpenShift
- Setup an entire sample Facebook App

This blog series should be EXACTLY what you're looking for.  You can find the first of three articles here:
http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/creating-a-facebook-app-setup-and-tool-installation/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with Spring Social module with has a good abstraction of the Facebook API.

You could then expose these services via REST with Spring Web Services or Jersey.

I am not sure about the hosting. Facebook should see it as a valid application no matter the host. Even your development computer/localhost cando it.